# Why is my edge function not working past the first row of pixels?

Tags: c, image-processing

I am creating an edge detection function that uses the Sobel edge detection algorithm to highlight perceived edges, but everything after my first row seems to be breaking.

I have tested the program on a variety of test images, all of which showed that after the first row of pixels, my program starts breaking!

Main function

```c
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "helpers.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Define allowable filters
    char *filters = "begr";

    // Get filter flag and check validity
    char filter = getopt(argc, argv, filters);
    if (filter == '?')
    {
        printf("Invalid filter.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Ensure only one filter
    if (getopt(argc, argv, filters) != -1)
    {
        printf("Only one filter allowed.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != optind + 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./filter [flag] infile outfile\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // Remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[optind];
    char *outfile = argv[optind + 1];

    // Open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 4;
    }

    // Open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 5;
    }

    // Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 6;
    }

    // Get image's dimensions
    int height = abs(bi.biHeight);
    int width = bi.biWidth;

    // Allocate memory for image
    RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store image.\n");
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        return 7;
    }

    // Determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // Iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Read row into pixel array
        fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr);

        // Skip over padding
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    // Filter image
    switch (filter)
    {
        // Blur
        case 'b':
            blur(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Edges
        case 'e':
            edges(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Grayscale
        case 'g':
            grayscale(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Reflect
        case 'r':
            reflect(height, width, image);
            break;
    }

    // Write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write new pixels to outfile
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Write row to outfile
        fwrite(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, outptr);

        // Write padding at end of row
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // Free memory for image
    free(image);

    // Close files
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);
    return 0;
}
```

My function

```c
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE new_image[height][width];
    int Gx[3][3] = {{-1, 0, 1}, {-2, 0, 2}, {-1, 0, 1}};
    int Gy[3][3] = {{-1, -2, -1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 1}};
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int gxRed = 0;
            int gxGreen = 0;
            int gxBlue = 0;
            int gyRed = 0;
            int gyGreen = 0;
            int gyBlue = 0;
            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
            {
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
                {
                    if ((i + x >= 0 && i + x < height) && (j + y >= 0 && j + y < width))
                    {
                        //initialize gx values for each color
                        gxRed += image[i + x][j + y].rgbtRed * Gx[x + 1][y + 1];
                        gxGreen += image[i + x][j + y].rgbtGreen * Gx[x + 1][y + 1];
                        gxBlue += image[i + x][j + y].rgbtBlue * Gx[x + 1][y + 1];
                        //initialize gy values for each color
                        gyRed += image[i + x][j + y].rgbtRed * Gy[x + 1][y + 1];
                        gyGreen += image[i + x][j + y].rgbtGreen * Gy[x + 1][y + 1];
                        gyBlue += image[i + x][j + y].rgbtBlue * Gy[x + 1][y + 1];

                    }
                }
            }
            int new_colorRed = round(sqrt(pow(gxRed, 2) + pow(gyRed, 2)));
            int new_colorGreen = round(sqrt(pow(gxGreen, 2) + pow(gyGreen, 2)));
            int new_colorBlue = round(sqrt(pow(gxBlue, 2) + pow(gyBlue, 2)));
            new_colorRed = (new_colorRed > 255) ? 255 : new_colorRed;
            new_colorGreen = (new_colorGreen > 255) ? 255 : new_colorGreen;
            new_colorBlue = (new_colorBlue > 255) ? 255 : new_colorBlue;
            new_image[i][j].rgbtRed = new_colorRed;
            new_image[i][j].rgbtGreen = new_colorGreen;
            new_image[i][j].rgbtBlue = new_colorBlue;
        }
        break;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = new_image[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Input image])
[image: Output image]

Comment: Are you modifying the same image you are reading from? As soon as you change it the changes roll downhill.

Comment: What does “start breaking” mean? Could you show the output on a small (maybe 10x10) example image?

Comment: @Sceptixe22 ,  1) `RGBTRIPLE new_image[height][width]` too big for local variable. 2) post image used and image created.  3) read/write in _binary_ mode.

Comment: Can you not see my code that I entered?

Comment: @Sceptixe22 Note updated comment.

Comment: If you do no transformation of the image, does the output match the input? If not, your reading and/or writing are wrong. If so, write input pixel values to the console to see if they match your expectation.  Also, you really should be doing this with a tiny image (15x10 or something like that), so you can better see what is going on and more easily debug your code. There is no point in using a large image right off the bat.

Comment: Please explain (to your rubber duck) the purpose of `break;` hiding at the bottom of the outer loop of `edges()`...

Comment: that appears to be your complete code, ~200 lines, which is a lot. please review the [mre] article. the point of the article is for you to debug your code and simplify it until the problem is pinned down. all the getopt stuff is a distraction. you could factor out the per-pixel kernel application into its own function.